# Post data to WCF service in iPhone application?

Tags: ios, json, web-services, post

I'm fairly new to IOS development, i need to post data to a service using native methods.

I think I need to do something like this?

```
NSString *content = @"field1=42&field2=Hello";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/SendEmail.svc/request"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]];

// generates an autoreleased NSURLConnection
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Am I going about this right as I'm not sure? I can post to the service successfully by either manually building the url or posting the json in fiddler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

- Create a web service method like this in your WCF service (Interface like or concrete service implementation):

  ```
  [OperationContract]
  [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "GetJourneys", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
  JourneyListResult GetJourneys(string sessionID);
  ```

The Request / Reponse objects can be any DataContract objects (will be serialized via .NET's `DataContractJsonSerializer`)

- Create a payload dictionary to use in your request:

  ```
  NSDictionary *payloadDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.sessionID,@"sessionID", nil];
  NSString *operationName = "GetJourneys";
  ```
- Create a request like this:

  ```
  NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
  urlRequest.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://url/of/your/Service.svc/" stringByAppendingString:operationName];
  [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
  [urlRequest addValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];

  NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:payloadDict options:0 error:NULL];
  [urlRequest setHTTPBody:jsonData];

  ITLog(@"Issuing request: %@ %@", self.operationName, [self payloadDict]);
  ```
- Send your request (backgroundQueue being a previously created NSOperationQueue. be sure to dispatch to the main queue(/thread) for UI processing):

  ```
  [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:backgroundQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
          if (!error && data.length > 0) {
              NSError *jsonError = nil;
              id jsonObj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonError];
              if (!jsonError && [jsonObj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                  // process result here
              } else {
                  // error handling
              }
          } else {
              // error handling
          }
      }];
  ```
- Decode/use the result

  ```
  if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
      NSArray *dictarr=(NSArray*)jsonObject;
      NSMutableArray *resultarr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      for (NSDictionary *dict in dictarr) {
          ITJourney *journey =[[ITJourney alloc]initWithDictionary:dict];
          [resultarr addObject:journey];
      }
      // use resultarr from here...
  }
  ```

You can see it put together in a small sample project i created for university here:

[App link](http://cl.ly/0T170O2U0f3E) and [WCF service link](http://cl.ly/3o3Z393C243r)

It also has session handling and binary streams for uploading images (very basic)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Martin for that post, it was very helpful. I had trouble getting mine to connect and after much poking around, I found that my svc was not accepting the json content-type. The fix for me was to add the  Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" attribute to the .SVC file, so:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="YourService" CodeBehind="YourService.svc.cs" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>
```

Hope this helps someone...

Answer (score -3):

I don't know what you mean by native methods, but if you are going to be doing alot of this and especially if you plan to queue requests, you may want to look into a third party library such as AFNetworking.

That said, if you are able to post to the service successfully, what's the question?